# Firestore collection

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, notifications

In my Firestore I have a collection of users in that collection document of each user named with its unique id, in each document I have a sub-collection named notification and that collection contains documents of notifications I'm trying to fetch those documents in recyclerview with snapshot listener but failed to do so here is my code and firestore please guide me if it is a good approach or should I  adapt any other way I don't know any other way to store firebase notification I'm new to android development

```
public class NotifFragment extends Fragment {

FragmentNotificationBinding binding;
NotificationAdapter notifAdapter;
ArrayList<Notification> list;
FirebaseFirestore database;
FirebaseAuth auth;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


 binding = FragmentNotificationBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), container, false);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    list = new ArrayList<>();


    notifAdapter = new NotificationAdapter(getContext(), list);


    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    DividerItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), layoutManager.getOrientation());
    binding.notifList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    binding.notifList.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
    binding.notifList.setAdapter(notifAdapter);

    database.collection("users")
            .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .collection("notification")
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                    if(error != null){
                        for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot: value.getDocuments()){
                            Notification notification = snapshot.toObject(Notification.class);
                            notification.setNotifId(snapshot.getString(notification.getNotifId()));
                            list.add(notification);
                        }
                        notifAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });

    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

[image]

I prepare notifications in my code like when user signup i prepare a welcome notification

```
Notification notification = new Notification();
notification.setTitle("Welcome");
notification.setNotifyAt(new Date().getTime());
notification.setBody("Welcome to M&M Store!");
database.collection("users")
        .document(uid).collection("notification").document()
        .set(notification);
```

Comment: If you try to log the value of `snapshot.getString(notification.getNotifId())`, is there something printed out in the logcat? If no, have tried to log the error message?

Comment: It just crash the activity take control to main and shows error to handle exception

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo entire app doesn't crash just close the notification fragment aand in logcat show to handle exception in on create method

Comment: @AlexMamo i want to ask can i save notification i send from firebase to this collection and show in same recyclerview

Comment: For sure you can. If the fragmnet closes, it's most likely because of a crash. So you have to check that.